# Chrome Extension "Folder" Button to Hold Other Chrome Buttons

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My question involves Google Chrome extension buttons, which you will see next to the "settings" button while running Google Chrome. I run many,many extensions which have buttons, and it's starting to take up too much real estate from the address bar. I'd like to know if there is any way for me to create an button which will hold extension buttons.

Ideally, this option already exists in the form of an extension I can install.  If that's not the case, I'll create my own extension.  That'd be a task.  C'est la vie.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to group all extension?

Answer (score 16):

That's not a real question ...
But at least in my chrome (v24, win7), I can drag the bar (the column that separate address bar from extensions icons) and by dragging that, icons will be grouped together in a drop-down list.